# Find the integral $\iint_R f(x,y)dA$ where R is the region bound by the curves $2y=1+x; x-y=1;y=x^2-1$ and $f(x,y)=2x$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm having troubles finding the integration limits primarily because when I plot the curves I get this:
[image]

And I'm not sure what exactly is the region to integrate,
[image]

is it R1 or R2? Or maybe both?

Comment: It is a poorly worded question. Unless the question gives further constraint, it is difficult to say whether it is $R1$ or $R2$. For example, if the question sought you to find area inside the parabola bound by the two lines, it could have stated $y \geq x^2-1$.

Comment: f(x,y)=2 may mean  point  (x, 2) i.e red region .